# WPF access parent ViewModel from inside a ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a TabControl with templated content as below:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem}" TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!--Some style stuff-->
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
             <!--Some structure stuff including a tabpanel and contentPresenter-->
        </ControlTemplate>
     </TabControl.Template>
     <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Button x:Name="MyButton" Visibility="{Binding x}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The view containing this TabControl uses a ViewModel similar to this:

```
public class MyPageViewModel : ScreenConductorViewModelBase<IMyTab>
{
    public Visibility x = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

I would like the visibility of the button inside the template to pull from my parent(?) ViewModel, however its trying to retrieve x from the items viewModel.

This makes sense to me but Im not sure how to specify that this field should come from the parent instead.

I've tried a few things but none of them seem to work:

```
   {Binding x}
   {Binding DataContext.x}
   {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=x}
```

Im sure it must be simple to do this but I cant seem to work out the binding syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}},
                             Path=DataContext.x}" />
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I also needed to change `public Visibility x = Visibility.Hidden;` to a property

Comment: It kinda feels like I'm doing something wrong and it doesn't fit well doing this with caliburn, Am i doing something dumb by doing this? do you know if there's a better way?